# Mac connects to network with no problem but browsers can't connect to websites

Tags: mac, network, internet, web-browsing

I am using macOS Mavericks (10.9.5) and Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all do not connect to websites even though the network is clearly connected.

But browsing when booted into safe mode works.

I've read many articles and tried the following solutions:

1. Set DNS servers to Google DNS and open DNS.
2. Reinstalled operating system through the internet recovery.  The internet for the recovery worked as expected, so this issue is something specific to browsing.
3. Added Chrome, Firefox, Safari to Mac firewall.
4. Removed System Configuration folder from library/preferences
5. Disabled McAffee antivirus put on by work IT
6. Ran McAffee scan and found nothing
7. Renewed DHCP

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Run network utility & see if you can ping stackechange.com &/or google.com If no, see if you can ping 104.16.14.128 & 216.58.208.46

Comment: I'll do that straight away.  I forgot to mention, that browsing works in safe mode and I'm using the subject Mac currently.  I'm going to have to log into regular mode then back into safe mode in order to post the results, so it will be a few minutes before I can tell you what happened.

Comment: Ping worked for all four.  No problems

Comment: So it's either a port or an app block... Check without firewall. Check for presence of LittleSnitch, which is a user Firewall if you don't know it. Maybe test https addresses like https://iforgot.apple.com to see if that can get through. Or maybe try Terminal nc -v portquiz.net 80 [or 8080, 443 etc]to see if a port is open [you appear to need to quit that after each query with Ctrl/c or subsequent queries go silent]

Comment: Okay.  Can't get to https sites.  Port test times out for each port.  Turning off firewall didn't work.  I know it's not https, but I tried fandango.com.  Interestingly, the fandango icon on the browser tab appeared before the browser timed out.

Comment: rebooted router recently? [I'm running out of ideas, though]

Comment: Yes.  And connected to different networks.  Tetsujin, thank you so much for taking the time to help me.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried creating a fresh account on the Mac? I'm presuming you didn't do a _clean_ install of the OS.

Comment: I had a similar problem, though with me it was just one site. Do ever remember editing `/private/etc/hosts` file? That's where I had the problem, run `cat /private/etc/hosts` and make sure it only has three lines other than the comments. You can also post it in a comment, it doesn't contain any confidential info. Also do have this issue if you connect to internet with WLAN, and Wifi?

Comment: If you can connect in Safe mode, then it means something is getting loaded after boot. Two usual culprits are kernel extensions, and Launch Agents/Daemon. Try `kextstat | grep -v com.apple`, and `launchctl list | grep -v com.apple`, to list those, respectively. Find anything you don't recognise? Like @Tetsujin said make sure you have any reverse firewall app like Little Snitch configured properly.

Comment: @calion, thanks for the question.  On your suggestion, I set up a new user account with no change to browsing performance.

Comment: @user14492, I got 4 lines from cat /private/etc/hosts:                   127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1               localhost 
fe80::1%lo0  localhost

Comment: @user14492, here are the results of keyextstat and launchctl:  [link] (http://imgur.com/7YPqqjB)  Not sure what I'd be looking for here, but I don't see anything that jumps out as unusual to me.

Comment: @user14492, finally, I have tried connecting through wireless and ethernet with same results.  Also, looked for little snitch specifically and didn't find it.  Not sure if the comp has any other reverse firewall app.

Comment: First thing, run this `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`, it should print out a few names. Them run `networksetup -setv6off <name>` name being the way you are currently connecting to internet (prob Wi-Fi). It should ask for you password. Then try connecting see if it works. I'm seeing a few of launch daemons with label `address.anonymous.*`, that don't make sense,  do you know what they might be. Because it's unusual for the label to be like this. I have none, perhaps they were installed by your Work IT guys? Try running the command in Safe Mode, it's a good chance it might be one of them.

Comment: Well, that definitely did something, but it didn't stick.  I ran the command in safe mode and logged back into regular mode.  I attempted to connect to a website.  The loading spinner in the browser tab moved fast as one would expect if it's working and the page title immediately loaded.  Then it processed for 15 seconds with no change. I figured it was reverting back to the previous behavior.  Interestingly, I went to kill the network and as soon as I did, the page loaded.  After that, every attempt to connect to a page timed out with no page load and a very slow loading spinner.

Comment: @user14492, sorry didn't answer your question.  Not sure what the anonymous launch daemons are.  I've been working on a Django app for a few months and had no problems.  Not sure if it could be related to that in any way?  Maybe a module I installed?  Though I haven't installed any recently.  I don't know.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant `networksetup` commands in regular mode. And run the `launchctl` & `kextstat` in safe mode. So you can see which ones are not loaded in safe mode, one of them could be the culprit. Anyways, it's good that the page loaded, so perhaps your network service is switching back to v6. You can check that with `networksetup -getinfo <name>`, also if you wanna read more just run `networksetup`. Have you tried creating a new account, and see if you can access the web there?

Comment: @user14492, I apologize for misunderstanding.  Good news though.  My team's IT manager was able to sort it out.  Turns out HBSS was not allowing me to browse because I needed to update McAffee, apparently.  He did some things related to that and I'm back up and running.  My organization's security settings are kind of interesting.  Anyway, I can't thank you enough for taking all of this time to help me.  I truly appreciate it.  You're very kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that HBSS was preventing browsing due to not having the latest McAfee updates.

Thanks to all who helped me through this!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my AV had entered a proxy that was blocking my connections.

It might be worthwhile to check:
System Preference > Network > Choose your connection > Advanced > Proxies > remove any active proxies

Answer (score 1):

I had my iMac in storage for one year and when I started it up again although I could see that the wifi is connected I could not browse the internet.
I contacted Apple Support and after deleting the contents of the folders below, the problem was solved.

Folders the contents of which were deleted are listed below:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents

~/Library/LaunchAgents

~/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

Comment: Perfect!!! After many tried in different way but no hope but this one help me, thanks Ahmed Azam.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @ahmed-azam helped me to solve the issue.

Symptoms:

- I can ping my router and all `arp` table (there were only 3 records)
- I cannot ping any host on the Internet (1.1.1.1, etc)
- Browsers have no connection

The things I tried without success:

- connect to working Wi-Fi that worked on other devices
- remove all networks from Network > Advanced... tab
- run Wireless Diagnostics
- renew DHCP lease / use of manual IP-address
- [removing files](https://appletoolbox.com/solved-macbook-connects-to-wi-fi-but-has-no-internet-connection/#10_Reset_your_network_preferences) from `/Library/Preferences/System Configuration`
- stopping **mDNSResponder**
- updating Time and Date
- creation of new Network Location

### My Solution

I removed 2 suspicious files from `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Then I looked into `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. I found only `.plist` files from Google Chrome, Microsoft Teams, etc. Also, there were files from Team Viewer and Windscribe VPN. I removed both applications (there is no need in them for me at the moment) and also removed their `.plist` files from both `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

After computer restart I successfully connected to the Internet!

I'm pretty sure the LaunchAgent/LaunchDaemons were the only thing that caused problems.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced for a few days the same issue on MacOS Sierra (10.12.5). 
No one of the suggestion found on internet seemed to work.

Finally, while installing the "**Little Snitch 4 Public Beta**" to check firewall trouble, the browser functionality suddenly springed back. I also choose to 'force quit' the installation to avoid to shut down or restart my Mac.

I guess that the Little Snitch installation overwrited some files, resolving the issue, without ever have to restart browsers or computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue after a recovery from Time Machine.

I had access to the internet but the applications refuse to connect except App Store and Apple Website on every browser.

I just deleted Little Snitch and the two files of Launch Deamons and Launch Agents and everything got back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

I could not access any internet site thru Tor, Chrome or Firefox until I disabled Litle Snitch.
It restarts by itself after 4 hours but in my case is OK because I seldom
use this applications.
Anyway I will try to pursue this problem to find a cleaner solution.

Comment: Why don't you just set up Little Snitch correctly instead?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.